# Jersey Jackson root name coming as ArrayList

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jackson

I have an array list of objects. ArrayList. The Employee class is annotated with @XMLRootElement(name = "employees"). I use jersey 1.8.1, Jackson 1.9.2 with POJOMappingFeature.The response is like

```
{
    ArrayList: [{name: John, age: 28}, {name: Mike, age:29}]
}
```

How do i make jackson display the correct root name (employees) in the json response. i tried using @JsonName(value = "employees") on Employee class also. I need to do this without using a list wrapper like EmployeeListWrapper with attribute List. i would like to have the response like

```
{
    employees: [{name: John, age: 28}, {name: Mike, age:29}]
}
```

Is it possible to do this using any jackson object mapper configuration. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did the answer help you to solve your issue?

Comment: Im afraid it didnt. Im using a custom object mapper resolver in jersey. There i have to return ObjectMapper.

Comment: But such an ObjectMapper (provided by your resolver) can be injected into your Jersey resource class and used directly.

Comment: With Jackson 2.x the JAX-RS resource method can be annotated with @JsonRootName annotation: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers

Answer (score 2):

You probably will not achieve this with `@XMLRootElement` or `@JsonRootName` annotations since the annotation would have to be put on the `ArrayList` class itself. And since you require to do it without any collection wrapper, then you will have to use Jackson `ObjectMapper` directly.

The mapper provides access to `ObjectWriter` builder,

> Builder object that can be used for per-serialization configuration of serialization parameters, such as JSON View and root type to use.

And the writer has `withRootName()` method that is what you need.

> Method for constructing a new instance with configuration that specifies what root name to use for "root element wrapping".

See code snippet below.

```
ObjectWriter writer = ObjectMapper.writer().withRootName("employees");
writer.writeValueAsString(employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Jackson may not recognize the [JAXB annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations) but you can customise [the object mapper](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQJaxRs) to do this.

If you want to stick to the Jackson annotations, you can use [@JsonRootName](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonRootName.html) to indicate name to use for root-level wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to override method findRootName() in [JaxbAnnotationIntrospector](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/xc/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.html) and use this inside ObjectMapper.

So the code will look like:

```
@Override
public String findRootName(AnnotatedClass ac) {
    // will return "employees" for @XmlType(name = "employees")
    // Or you can return the class name itself
    return ac.getAnnotations().get(XmlType.class).name();
}
```

Reference: [Customizing root name in Jackson JSON provider](http://www.texient.com/2015/02/customizing-root-node-name-in-jaxb-jackson-json-processor.html)